# Install Libpostal in docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

Is there any solution to install libpostal in a running container?

I got this error when typing `pip install postal`:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for postal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`.

```
 running build_ext
      building 'postal._expand' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/postal
      gcc -pthread -B /opt/conda/compiler_compat -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/conda/include/python3.11 -c postal/pyexpand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/postal/pyexpand.o -std=c99
      postal/pyexpand.c:2:10: fatal error: libpostal/libpostal.h: No such file or directory
          2 | #include <libpostal/libpostal.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for postal
  Running setup.py clean for postal
Failed to build postal
ERROR: Could not build wheels for postal, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
$ pip install libpostal
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpostal (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libpostal
```

After many research, I couldn't come to install it.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  jupyter:
    container_name: jupyter
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
    volumes:
      - .:/home/jovyan/
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the complete error?  Depending on the library, sometimes Python libraries can need things like a C toolchain to build.  Installing this in a Dockerfile is usually easier and more reproducible than trying to do it in a running container, plus it won't be lost when the container exits.

Comment: It's worth noting that `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` is no longer updated on Docker Hub in favor of [the new host at `quay.io`](https://quay.io/repository/jupyter/pyspark-notebook); you should probably update your `image` reference.

Answer (score 0):

[The `postal` Python bindings for `libpostal`](https://github.com/openvenues/pypostal) are just that - bindings - and don't include any of the core foundation model components on installation.

Per the docs, you need to install the [`libpostal` C library itself](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal) in your container/execution environment prior to using the Python bindings.

As the `jupyter/pyspark-notebook` container you're trying to use this with is Ubuntu-based, you can follow the guidance labeled "On Ubuntu/Debian" in either of the linked `README`s by running the following commands in the container's shell:

> ## Installation
>
> Before using the Python bindings, you must install the libpostal C library. Make sure you have the following prerequisites:
>
> #### On Ubuntu/Debian
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install curl autoconf automake libtool python-dev pkg-config
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> #### Installing libpostal
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal
> cd libpostal
> ./bootstrap.sh
> ./configure --datadir=[...some dir with a few GB of space...]
> make
> sudo make install
>
> # On Linux it's probably a good idea to run
> sudo ldconfig
> ```

A common pitfall: be sure you update the `[...some dir with a few GB of space...]` placeholder to an absolute reference on your mounted filesystem where the `libpostal` `Makefile` can download the various weights and supporting files you'll need.

Once the build completes, you'll then be able to install the Python bindings you were trying to use originally:

```
python3 -m pip install postal
```

---

Alternatively, you may find success in building your own `Dockerfile` to perform a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) firstly of your Jupyter environment, then `libpostal` with one of the community-supported `libpostal` containers. I personally can't speak to this method's efficacy but it seems like it should be well within the realm of possibility.